# Changing h1 element based on input element content Vanilla JS

Tags: javascript

Why the h1 tag does not change?
Is there anything wrong?

I tried it with alert and it worked perfectly. I mean whenever I typed into input box the alert message showed me the characters. but how about h1 tag?
what did I do wrong?

Here is my snippet:

```js
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  font-size: 2rem;
  font-family: 'Georama', sans-serif;
}
body {

  background-color: #555;
  color: #fff;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100vh;
  align-items: center;
}

button {
  cursor: pointer;
}

.container {
  width: auto;
  height: 100px;
}

.te {
  display: block;
  color: white;
}
```

```css
const text = document.getElementById('pps');

pass.addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  const val = e.target.value;
  text.innerHTML(val);
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <html>
    <head>
      <meta charset="utf-8" />
      <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
      <title>Page Title</title>
      <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
      <script src="main.js" defer></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form class="container">
        <label>Type here:</label>
        <input
          type="text"
          placeholder="insert here.,.."
        />
      </form>
      <h1 class="te" id="pps">PP</h1>
    </body>
  </html>
</html>
```

Comment: Whenever doing web development, when something doesn't work, open the devtools and look at the console. `innerHTML` is a *property*, not a method. You assign to it (`.innerHTML = "..."`), you don't call it (not `.innerHTML("...")`).

Comment: `text.innerHTML = val;` .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two mistakes here:

1. As it was mentioned in comments innerHTML is property, not a method, so should be called text.innerHTML = e.target.value;
2. You didn't assign anything to the 'pass' variable.

Also, there's no sense to create the variable if you are going to use the value only once, so we can remove `const val = e.target.value;` and just use e.target.value directly.

I've attached the working snippet below.

```js
const text = document.getElementById('pps')

document.getElementById('textInput').addEventListener('input', (e) => {
  text.innerHTML = e.target.value;
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
  <title>Page Title</title>
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="screen" href="main.css" />
  <script src="main.js" defer></script>
</head>

<body>
  <form class="container">
    <label>Type here:</label>
    <input type="text" id="textInput" placeholder="insert here..." />
  </form>
  <h1 class="te" id="pps">PP</h1>
</body>

</html>

</html>
```